# Poisson with an autoregressive term

Tags: r, poisson-distribution, autoregressive

I want to fit a fairly "standard" Poisson model, but with an autoregressive term.

$N_i \sim \mathrm{Pois}( \lambda_i E_i)$

with $\log \lambda_i = X_i \beta + \delta$

$\delta \sim AR(1)$

$X_i$ is a vector of covariates.
$\beta$ are my coefficients.
$\delta$ is an autoregressive term.
$E_i$ is the size of population at time t.

The idea is that the count at time step $t$ is partially dependent on the count at time step $t-1$.

Ideally, I'd like to find some R package to fit this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It would be good to consider accepting answers to some of your previous questions, all of which have received multiple answers, thus giving you some choice. There is a check mark next to each answer that you can click on to indicate which one has been addressed your query.

Comment: Can you give some more detail as to what kind of autoregressive structure you want to assume. It's a little ambiguous at the moment. Defining $E_i$ would also be helpful. Cheers. :)

Comment: This is an epidemiological model.  The dependent variable is the number of people with a disease at time t.  I can fit it reasonably well with a "standard" poisson, but it was suggested that an autoregressive term might work well for this particular study.

Comment: I guess I'm wondering what sort of autoregressive formulation you want. Are you thinking of something like $\log \lambda_i= X_i \beta + \alpha \log \lambda_{i-1} + \varepsilon_i$  where $\varepsilon_i$ is some additional randomness driving the evolution of the rate parameter? And, if this is an epidemiological model, is $N_i$ some number of, say, infected individuals? If so, then it would seem $\lambda_i \ll 1$, otherwise there is nonnegligible probability of more people than exist in the population becoming infected at time $i$. But, maybe I'm misunderstanding what you're aiming for.

Comment: You understand perfectly.  Nice summary.  $N_i$ is the number of people with the disease and $\lambda$ is definitely less than 1.

Comment: -1, there is no autoregression in the model you wrote. Fix the model and I will undo the downvote. The second problem is $\lambda_i$ vs $E_i$ vs $N_i$ - what is the difference between $E_i$ and $N_i$? The $Pois(\lambda_i E_i)$ looks too weird. Normally it is like $Pois(\lambda_i)$ and if there is something more *at all* then it is an overdispersion: $Pois(\lambda_i \sigma)$.

Comment: Curious - you are incorrect. The Expectation of a Poisson process can be a factor of the rate and population.  So, $Pois(\lambda_i E_i)$ is correct notation.  There is also a very clear autoregressive term in the model I specified.

Comment: The package `acp` fits autoregressive conditional Poisson models in R. This may be of some use.

Answer (score 5):

I think you are looking for the model in [Brandt et al. (2000)](https://www.utdallas.edu/~pbrandt/Patrick_Brandts_Website/Research_files/bwfp2000.pdf) there called PEWMA, after the forecast function.  R code to fit it is available [here](http://www.utdallas.edu/~pbrandt/code/pests.r).

The paper also has some general discussion of possible conditionally Poisson AR models.  Fro more of that, chapter 7 of [Cameron and Trivedi (1998)](http://www.cup.org/titles/catalogue.asp?isbn=0521635675) is useful.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a Transfer Function between N and E and your other covariates which could encode changes in parameters over time , changes in error variance over time , any necessaery autoregressive structure possibly proxying unspecified seasonal drivers and other omitted structure like level shifts, seasonal pulses and local time trends. Accomplished without letting "unusual values" distort the model/parameters. I have seen approaches like this referred to in the literature as DARIMA MODELS where the D stands for discrete. Various forms of Power Transforms such as Logs might be needed to possibly decouple the expected value from the variance of the errors ( always a good idea when needed! ) These kinds of models can be useful in detecting the possible impact of changes in N as it relates to the prediction of E.

Comment: Without getting into too many details, I don't believe that model would work for this data set.  What I have are the counts of disease along with some categorial factors for each year.  (i.e. Asian, Men, 2005, 10 out of 500 had disease.)